# What is a good IDE for client side JavaScript development?

Tags: web-development, javascript, ide

I recently started learning JavaScript and am looking for a good JavaScript Editor/IDE. I found dozens of them in a Google search but I would appreciate if users who have experience with using such an IDE could recommend one.

I want an IDE with **syntax highlighting**, possibly **IntelliSense** and **debugging support** for JavaScipt code. I'm a **Windows 7** user and do just **client-side** JavaScript development.

Any suggestions??

Comment: @nK0de if it's only client-side, then Firebug should take care of all your debugging needs

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203991/what-tool-to-use-for-javascript-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880/javascript-ides, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925219/best-javascript-editor-or-ide-with-intellisense-and-debugging-possibly

Comment: @KimBurgess: all are broken links

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19923537 & http://stackoverflow.com/q/788978

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My personal favourite is Aptana Studio. It's Eclipse with Plugins for web development preinstalled and will get you going without any problems. Aptana is very comfortable and has all the features you want.

However almost all common IDEs will have either builtin support for Javascript or offer plugins for the language. Netbeans and IntelliJ are good,too.

Since you said IntelliSense I guess you're using VisualStudio. You'll easily find support for Javascript in it and maybe it will be most convenient to stick with it.

Comment: @ downvoter care to comment ?

Comment: Maybe because Aptana is a mediocre tool

Comment: that's why I said its my PERSONAL favourite and pointed to other possibilities. Questions like "what is the best" will always get opinions as answers

Comment: you should totally try WebStorm instead ;) (btw I didn't downvote, it's fine to have personal favourites)

Comment: @lhk I've been hearing good news about both Aptana and WebStrom. Guess I'll have to see for myself. Thank you :)

Comment: Thumbs up on Webstorm. Haven't tried Aptana since the first time it crashed for me which was about the same time it almost loaded.

Answer (score 19):

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html#JavaScript) fits your requirements like no other. I'm an old timer IntelliJ user and believe me, those folks know how to make an IDE.

And they are offering a special pricing before February 1.

Comment: I like webstorm, but my only complain is I cannot have multiple project in same window, Which is bit odd for an IDE

Answer (score 7):

There are no good JavaScript IDEs. There are only [Type 3](http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikitech-l/2011-May/053231.html) IDEs for JavaScript. The "best" IDE currently would be WebStorm 3.0.

Use a text editor of your choice instead. Good choices include:

- [vim](http://www.vim.org/)
- [sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

vim and sublime text support syntax highlighting and allow you to run command line or build scripts through the editor.

As for debugging JavaScript, for client-side, use the browser to debug it. For node, use node-inspector (the browser) to debug it.

As for intellisense, you don't need it and it will be wrong 10% of the time. Personally the fact that it gets it wrong 10% of the time is enough of a productivity hit to just not use it all. Again, WebStorm 3 is the only IDE that gets it 90% right here. VS2011 might also make for a good contender but I have not tried it personally. VS2010 is horrible for JavaScript.

Comment: Any reason for a downvote?

Comment: I think I'm gonna try Aptana and WebStorm as many have suggested. Thank you. I didn't downvote your answer btw.

Comment: The central tenant of that article seems to be that all IDEs are either perfect (Type 1) or counter-productive (Type 3). I don't agree with this. For those who haven't read the article, a Type 2 IDE is a text editor, i.e. no IDE at all.

Comment: Might want to add that vim also has auto-completion; it's a bit different from intellisense in that it works dumbly on strings, but for a highly dynamic language like javascript, this is actually an advantage (e.g., it even works inside string literals). Vim has a pretty harsh learning curve though.

Comment: @tdammers all text editors have auto completion. But that's true.

Comment: @Don It is true, text editors are very powerful and lightweight tools, an IDE has to be right 99% of the time, for me if an IDE is wrong 10% of the time then I'm better of doing it by hand, i.e. it's counter productive.

Comment: @Raynos: VS2010 is quite good for JavaScript if you install the JScript Editor Extensions (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed). Otherwise, yes, it's horrible. You may maybe mention it in your answer?

Comment: @MainMa that plugin might bring VS2010 upto "almost as good as a text editor but totally bloated"

Comment: I don't really agree with that article either. Eclipse is perfectly fine for PHP; the visual debugger works great (you have to know how to set it up, though, and install the zend debugger). It's not that great for javascript for reasons others mentioned, but it still brings much more to the table than a simple text editor, and there's no reason its javascript support necessarily has to suck. If it had some way of "extern"ing things it would be fine. I need to try netbeans for js and see if it does a better job...

Comment: @GGG "they'll desperately cling to type 
(3) tools even when they make their lives miserable."

Comment: @Raynos I don't think this is a symptom of that, I normally use a simple text editor. I use eclipse for PHP if I want to use the debugger or need to do refactoring that is complex enough that I'm worried I'll screw it up with sed. It certainly doesn't make my life miserable, and has nice autocompletion, popup help for user defined and built-in functions, debugger, etc. same for PHP as it does for Java. Zend's own PHP IDE is based on eclipse itself, in fact. Making eclipse seem like some kind of second-rate tool for PHP implies that the author of that article is clueless.

Comment: the 'Type 3' link appears to be misdirected, landing on a short Wikimedia email about how page title search works.

Comment: That article is insightful for someone that doesn't regularly try out new tools. I would have agreed with the author's statement about no Type 1 tools for dynamically typed languages until I found the JetBrains tools. They are Type 1 tools for dynamic languages.

Comment: I found that if I delete CSS too fast in certain versions of VS, VS crashes (and no, it doesn't matter how many damn parsers you turn off). Type whatever. Hell no.

Answer (score 5):

My project was an [Atlassian JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) plugin: Java, SQL, some [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html) templates in the back-end and few dashboard gadgets (JavaScript/HTML/CSS) in the frond-end. Atlassian also have their own frameworks for the plugins, so it is helpful if an IDE has support for nonstandard external libraries.

I've had quite unpleasant experience with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)'s JavaScript support, it has numerous glitches with completion and automatic code formatting, especially with complex code (modular sources, few frameworks used, etc.). Refactoring is not always works as intended (or at all) and almost useless. I've not tried Aptana Studio though.

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) is somewhat better in this regard but its support for complex mixed source projects (like Java/JavaScript/web/templates etc.) is lacking (maybe I've not tried hard enough).

Finally I've ended up using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/index.jsp). It is commercial (there is 30 day trial) but unbeatable feature-wise. Code analysis, semantic coloring, refactoring which works across various source files (like js, css, html). Just try it and you would never look back.

P.S. I'm not affiliated with JetBrains in any way, it's just my personal view.